# Error while installing truffle using "npm i truffle -g"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, web3js, truffle

While installing Truffle on my desktop, an anonymous error occurs...

[image]

First it's showing the error related to python which is strange but then I install python now this error

```
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\Tanuj Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\leveldown
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.2 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.31829.152) found at:
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Tanuj Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\leveldown
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tanuj Sharma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-23T11_22_31_900Z-debug.log
```

My vscode is already in latest version

[image]

npm: '8.1.2',
node: '16.13.2',
v8: '9.4.146.24-node.14',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me:

The node-gyp docs state that "node-gyp requires that you have installed a compatible version of Python, one of: v3.6, v3.7, v3.8, or v3.9.", and I had 3.10.2, as I notice you do.

- Run `npm install --global windows-build-tools`. Since this installs some 2.7 Python version, i uninstalled it to do the next step.
- Install Python 3.9 (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3910/)
- Install node-gyp: `npm install -g node-gyp`
- Clear npm cache: `npm cache clear --force`
- Finally hit `npm i -g truffle`

By the way, Im running Windows 10, with Node 16.14.0 and npm 8.3.1

Answer (score 1):

You have to install Visual Studio Community 2022 as well as Visual Studio Code. And when installing Visual Studio Community, you have to install desktop development with C++ with some optional packages.

[image: Image of visual studio and where to click on]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue used this code: `npm install -g truffle@5.4.29`